# MySQL - Complex INNER JOIN and CONCAT Query error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an error `ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'year_fk' in 'field list'` on this query:

```
    SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('year:', year_pk) AS global_id,
       year_name AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM year 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS global_id,
       unit_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM unit
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS global_id,
       rotation_discipline_block_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM rotation_discipline_block rdb
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS global_id,
       week_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM week wk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN week wk ON wk.week_pk = le.week_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
ORDER BY name
```

Not sure which part of the query that contains year_fk though...

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pBwNx74Qv5u1igxxXy2rN/2)

Comment: Run each SELECT stand-alone...

Comment: Table `week` doesn't have a column `year_fk`

Comment: @HoneyBadger Where do you see week.year_fk in the query?

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 5th query of the union, the one that selects from `week`...

Comment: Still not sure where the problem is, as e.g. table rotation_discipline_block doesn't have year_fk, yet that works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it myself:

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('year:', year_pk) AS global_id,
       year_name AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM year 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS global_id,
       unit_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM unit
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS global_id,
       rotation_discipline_block_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM rotation_discipline_block rdb
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS global_id,
       week_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM week wk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN week wk ON wk.week_pk = le.week_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
ORDER BY name
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pBwNx74Qv5u1igxxXy2rN/3)